# PanclusGz has no attribute date_solareclipse

Tags: python, attributeerror

I used panclus module in python to calculate the date of solar eclipse but it was showing that it has no attribute named `date_solareclipse`. Below is my code please check.

```
from PanclusGz import Gz as gz
print(gz.date_solareclipse)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct name is `date_solar_eclipse`; and it is a function, so you're missing the parenthesis!

Try the following:

```
from PanclusGz import Gz as gz
print(gz.date_solar_eclipse())
```